# how to copy all the files and folders to Cloudflare R2

Tags: ubuntu, command-line-interface, cloudflare, ubuntu-20.04, bucket

I was trying to backup all the files and folders in my local PC.

I figure it out how to connect to R2 by wrangler.

[image]

Is there away to copy an hole folders to R2?

For example there's a bucket 'A' in R2.

And I want to copy all the files and folder from my local path(example : /home/alex/A) to R2 bucket 'A'

Is there a cli(wrangler) to copy? or do I need to use an other way?

Comment: SO is for programming questions only, so OS/cloud storage support is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). You could possibly ask on [ubuntu.se] or [sf] instead.

Answer (score 1):

Both rclone (cli) and s3fs (FUSE) work. Here's an example on how to configure rclone: https://developers.cloudflare.com/r2/examples/rclone/.

You can also upload files via the dashboard as long as each individual file is < 300 MiB.